# Looking for ideas: An easy way to automatically press a key at computer restart

Tags: digital-logic, video, vga, pc

I'm looking to make a restart solution for a computer that doesn't necessitate manual input.  I have a server with a BIOS that, when every slot of memory is full, automatically downgrades the speed of all the memory - it's an architecture limitation - and I'm running it with all slots full.

The result is that on startup, I get a message warning me that system settings have been changed due to "overclocking". (Which isn't entirely accurate.  The memory speed has been automatically reduced, but that's what it does).  I cannot get rid of this message no matter how many BIOS settings I change - it seems to be a fixed limitation.

Every time the system restarts, I have to manually hit enter on the keyboard to acknowledge the warning.  This makes it really un-handy when Microsoft decides to force an update of Windows, or a power failure occurs (no UPS) when I'm away from home.

Before you say "replace it with a better one", I'm wondering if there is another solution to detect the message and emulate a press of the Enter key.

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Some other things to consider: Is there a signal (even something like the power LED or similar) that gets toggled at restart, which you can monitor and use to press Enter on a delay?

Comment: Does the Bios support RAM setup for delays. Have you tried matching RAM in pairs? And run MEMTEST, can you raise the RAM voltage in Bios? That makes it run faster but warmer. You can also modify Registry to force no reboots on updates or go to manual every Tuesday.

Comment: You could hook up an Arduino between the keyboard and the PC to send a keypress after a certain delay after boot up. There are probably Arduino keyloggers pre-built that have all the hardware set up. You would only need to reprogram the mpu. Or you could build one yourself.

Comment: An arduino can probably act as a ps/2 keyboard, or you could just tear apart an old keyboard and integrate that into your project, so you don't have to mess with your primary keyboard.

Comment: This sounds like the sort of nuissance quirk that a self-respecting motherboard vendor would correct by a BIOS update. Are you running a fresh BIOS ?

Comment: If you still have this problem, do you have mismatched RAM. This is a common symptom. Sometimes swapping RAM  slots by testing with MEMTEST on a bootable disk can validate RAM speed performance using at least 8 to the sequential tests. Otherwise I would use a cheap computer to listen to the server for activity and arrange to send a response to mimick an enter character every minute until normal activity was sensed using any serial port  type. Without knowing your H/W sensing activity is fairly easy but hard to explain without details.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem (need to perform an action *n* seconds after each reboot), as that server's BIOS initialized its built-in serial port handshaking lines in a specific way, early in the boot process. I could detect that, start a timer, and then perform the action needed (in your case, that would be pressing the Enter key).

It's easy to act on a power-on event, and either use a modified real keyboard, or a microcontroller acting as a USB HID device, to send the Enter keypress.

The challenge will be for you to detect a *reboot*, without a power-cycle, since simple detection (e.g. looking for a power-cycle on USB Vbus) may not allow you to detect a *reboot*, only a power-on boot - it all depends on your server's behavior.

So if you can accept the simple algorithm of "simulate pressing the Enter key *n* seconds after every boot and reboot", then you need to find a detectable event on your server, which occurs on every boot *and* reboot, before the Enter key needs to be pressed.

Examples of possible events for you to detect in your MCU:

- Server serial port initialization, as I used. (Does your server have a built-in, preferably unused, serial port which it initializes early in the boot process? Or does your server's BIOS initialize an attached USB-Serial adapter during boot?)
- USB Vbus cycling. (Does your server cycle its USB Vbus on a reboot?)
- USB Keyboard enumeration.
  If your server supports a USB keyboard (not only PS/2-style) then it must have already enumerated the keyboard early in the boot process, for it to then be able to recognize that Enter keypress from it later during boot, when you want to press it (or simulate it).

  So a more complex solution would be to use a suitable MCU with a USB stack, program that as a HID device i.e. a keyboard, and then detect when the server detects and enumerates that HID device, as that indicates a boot or reboot has occurred - which is exactly what you want to detect.

  Then you can send the Enter keypress from your MCU's HID device, a suitable time after the USB enumeration has occurred.
- LED flashes on motherboard (some servers provide status information via motherboard LEDs)
  If you can detect a unique LED light pattern during boot and reboot, then an MCU can identify that using a photodiode / phototransistor etc.

Summary: It all depends what easily-detectable event(s) occur on your server during both a boot *and* reboot. Identifying such event(s) should be your next step. Then you can investigate how to get an MCU to act on one of those events. It should always be possible to use USB HID enumeration as that detectable event, but the required MCU programming will be more complex than just detecting a change of voltage, or a flashing LED etc.).